# How to have a useEffect that uses `router.push` and should only fire for `router.query.id` changes in a Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, html5-history, next-router

I need to transition between 2 routes in a NextJs app like the one on the following example:

```
FROM: /some-route?id=ID_1
TO:   /some-route?id=ID_1&page=2
```

And I have a `useEffect` that does something like this:

- Should fire for any `id` change
- Makes use of `router.push` for some reason

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const { query, push } = useRouter();
const { id } = query; 

useEffect(() => {
  try {
    fetchDataFor(id);
  }
  catch(err) {
    push('/not-found');
  }
},[id,push]);
```

The problem I'm facing with this is related to the fact that the whole `router` object will change from the route update, and my effect will re-run because of the `push` method reference change, even though my `id` is not changing.

I'm currently having to check if the `id` has been updated or not by using some `useRef` variable that keeps track of the previous value. That's cumbersome.

I thought that maybe I should use a dynamic route, like:

```
/some-route/[id]
/some-route/[id]?page=2
```

But I guess the problem will remain, because of the `push` property that will keep on changing because of the querystring change.

Another option would be omitting the `push` method from the useEffect's dependency array. But that seems like an anti-pattern.

What would be the best approach to solve this issue?

The goal here is being able to use `router.push` (or at least be able to push another route somehow) inside the `useEffect` that should only run for `query.id` updates.

Comment: Just omit `push` why do even put it here? It is not a bad practice, totally fine thing.